# mismatch between number of documents indexed in solr and file count in linux

Tags: linux, solr, ls, wc

I have a ton of documents in a directory but I dont know how many there are. I used the command

ls -lf xmlFiles | wc -l

to count, and it gives 981,266 files.

The issue is I ran another command to index them into solr

find xmlFiles/ -exec /opt/solr/bin/post -c myCollection {} \;

and this command is still running. When I check the solr number of files indexed, it currently yields 1,214,436 files.

My question is, why is there a mismatch here? Ive searched for an answer to this problem and could not find one. Any ideas?

Comment: `ls -lf xmlFiles` will show the files in the current directory. There may be more within subdirectories in `xmlFiles/`

Comment: nope, not the case in this situation

Comment: if you add the -type f flag to only find files you get the same number minus 1(for the enclosing directory)